# How to connect to user's stream in TokBox

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, opentok, tokbox

I'm making a 1 on 1 video call app using TokBox.
I'm opening a session using this code:

`[_session connectWithApiKey:kApiKey token:kToken];`

after getting the didConnect message i'm publishing a stream on one user device using this code:

```
    _publisher = [[OTPublisher alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [_publisher setName:@"PublishName"];
    [_session publish:_publisher];
    [self.view addSubview:_publisher.view];
    [_publisher.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, widgetWidth, widgetHeight)];
```

What do I need to transfer to the other user in order for him to see what the first user publishes? I tried going through the docs but It's really unclear to me.
Do I need a session ID? Publish ID?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of sessions as rooms. People connected to the same session will be in the same room so they are able to see each other. Lets say you have 2 iPhones, A and B. After iPhone A calls `[_session publish...]`, iPhone B will get a stream created event with A's video stream. Simply subscribe to that stream and B should be able to see As video.

You probably want to have a streamCreated delegate. In your streamCreated delegate, simply call `[session subscribe...]` to subscribe to the publishing stream.

For an example, check out the [OpenTok HelloWorld Tutorial](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-webrtc/tree/master/samples). Its a simple group video chat where everybody is publishing and subscribing to each other.

Comment: Hi.
Suppose that, i have three streams, then how will i get that stream on which user click.