# clicking mic or audio icon(button) ends the video chat in opentok

Tags: javascript, webrtc, videochat, opentok, tokbox

**What happens is that I get a mic icon(button) and speaker icon , and on clicking any of them the video chat is over.**

[image]

**I don't know what is happening. You can check in images.**

[image]

**On clicking any of the two icons some code runs somewhere and the video chat session is disonnected.
And the new screen would be empty like this**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to previous question, and the answer from that question applies here as well: [How to connect to user's stream in TokBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736569/how-to-connect-to-users-stream-in-tokbox)